# Inequality from IMO 2000 problem 4 question $\prod\limits_{cyc}\left(a-1+\frac{1}{b}\right)\leq 1$ $abc=1$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, optimization, contest-math

I know the problem is repeated but my question is somehow different. I want to know whether my proof is correct because I have troubles with the last part.

Since $abc=1$ we can homogenize the variables being $$a=\frac{x}{y}$$ $$b=\frac{y}{z}$$ $$c=\frac{z}{x}$$

Hence the asked inequality is converted into $$(x+y-z)(y+x-z)(z+y-x)\leq xyz$$ But I searched on the internet and it seems that it has only a solution for $x,y,z$ when they are sides of a triangle. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x,y,z$ are not the sides of a triangle, then the inequality is trivial because the left hand side would negative.

Answer (score 0):

Your trouble come from the fact that you have taken a **product** $(x+y-z)(y+x-z)(z+y-x)$ instead of a **sum**...

Comment: What do you mean with this?

Comment: Simply that you had a $\Sigma_{cyc}$ which means "summation" that you have converted into a product $(x+y-z) \times (y+x-z) \times (z+y-x)$...

Comment: Oh sorry I meant to say $\Pi_{cyc}$

Comment: It is not too late to give us a pointer to a site where we can have the "official" proof.

Comment: Well it is on google but the solution is multipling terms which is a little ugly I think.